# Select X.A and X.B from X, then count all rows from Y where Y.A = X.A and Y.B > X.B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables: **conversations**, **participants**, and **messages**:

```
+---------------+
| conversations |
+---------------+
| id            |
+---------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                     participants                    |
+-----------------+----------------+------------------+
| conversation_id | participant_id |     last_read    |  // "participant_id" is the id of the user.
+-----------------+----------------+------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                            messages                           |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------------------+---------+
| id | conversation_id | sender_id |   sending_time   | content |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------------------+---------+
```

[Sample data on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/618b43/5)

My ultimate goal is to count the total number of messages the user did not read. If the message `sending_time` is grater then the conversation `last_read` value, then the user did not read the message.

**Example (using the sample data):** Let's say I want to count the number of unread messages of user `2`. As we can see in the sample data, in conversation `1` he received 2 messages from user `1` (messages `1` and `3`), and in conversation `2` he recieved 1 message from user `1` (message `4`). Since user `2` last read conversation `1` at 10:30, there is 1 unread message in conversation `1` (message `3`), and since he did not yet read conversation `2`, there is 1 unread message in conversation `2`, so we have a total of **2** unread messages in all conversations, and that should be the result.

My first try was to approach this part-SQL part-Code. So first I executed the following query from my C# program, which fetches all the conversations the user participates in:

```
SELECT conversation_id, last_read
FROM participants
WHERE participant_id = {user_id}
```

Then, for each result of the previous query, I executed the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM messages
WHERE
    conversation_id = {result.conversation_id}
    AND
    sender_id <> {user_id}
    AND
    sending_time > {result.last_read}
```

And finally, I programmatically summed up the results of all the `COUNT`s. All of this works just fine.

However, for many reasons, I need to refactor this code to be 100% SQL, and I am not sure how to accomplish this. I believe that the process should be along the lines of the "query" in the title. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will greatly help us here. We have an "idea", but no data or end goal to work with; making this difficult to answer.

Comment: @Larnu - Sure! I will edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Larnu - Please review my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just a `join` with appropriate filters:

```
select count(*)
from messages m join
     participants p
     on p.conversation_id = m.conversation_id 
where p.participant_id = {user_id} and
      p.last_read < m.sending_time;
```

Comment: Thanks. On the sample data I added to the question the result I get is 0 while I need to get 2.

Comment: @Sipo . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert into sql query try this.

```
select count * from  conversations c join  participants p on conversations.id = participants.conversation_id join messages m on messages.conversation_id = participants.conversation_id where  m.sender_id > p.last_read
```